# Can we pass dynamically server name and database name in application.properties

Tags: java, reactjs, sql-server, spring, spring-boot

Lets suppose we have a different servers and different databases. I want to change it dynamically as we a application.properties, we can write only 1 server name and database name in it. so is there any way to write connection url dynamically and passes the server name and database name from front end(React-js). if yes please elaborate it with code thank you

Can we pass dynamically server name and database name in application.properties

Comment: Idea behind properties file is to keep values dynamic so you don't hard code in the code! As @muhamad said , if your app is using many values which you want you to be dynamic, consider a config server

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to pass the server name and database name from the front-end to the application.properties file.

What you can do is to use environment variables to set the server name and database name at runtime. Just set them before starting your application and then use the ${VAR_NAME} syntax in the application.properties file to reference the environment variables.

The end result in your application.properties could be like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST}:3306/${DB_NAME}
```

otherwise you can use a configuration server, such as Spring Cloud Config, which allows you to externalize the configuration of your application and manage the configuration in a central location.

Comment: Hi can you please elaborate with the code because i am new in spring boot